# ngModel returns date as an array instead of default date format

Tags: angular

i'm trying to bind data using ngModel in angular, all the fields work pretty fine in my form and i'm getting the expected data unless that date fields return an array instead of default date format and format that i'm not able to see the data whenever I open the form to edit it!

The screenshot below shows the log of the object containing array dates.

[image: Screenshot of the log of the clicked element]

and here is my html code:

```
                   <div class="mb-3">
                   <label class="form-label">Date Début</label>
                    <input
                     type="date"
                     name="date_debut"
                     class="form-control"
                     [(ngModel)]="currentMission.date_debut"
                     />
                     </div>
                   <div class="mb-3">
                      <label class="form-label">Date Fin</label>
                      <input
                      type="date"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="date_fin"
                      [(ngModel)]="currentMission.date_fin"
                      />
                      </div>
```

and my ts code:

```
onEditClicked(id:any) {
    let actualMission = this.missions.find((m) => {return m.id === id})
    console.log(actualMission);
    this.currentMission = actualMission;
  }
```

add mission ts code:

```
addMission(): void {
    const data = {
      nom:this.mission.nom,
      user_id:1,
      date_debut:this.mission.date_debut,
      date_fin:this.mission.date_fin,
      tjm:this.mission.tjm,
      prolongeable:this.mission.prolongeable
      }

    this.missionService.createMission(data).subscribe({
      next:(res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.submitted=true;
      },
      error:(e)=> console.error(e)
      
    })
    this.router.navigate(['/missions/missions-list'])
    alert('Mission created')
  }
```

add mission html:

```
<div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="date_debut">Date Début</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_debut"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="mission.date_debut"
            name="date_debut">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="date_fin">Date Fin</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_fin"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="mission.date_fin"
            name="date_fin">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="d-grid">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addMission()">Enregistrer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

add mission service:

```
 createMission(data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/`, data);
      }
```

Since it returns an array, I cannot view the current selected date whenever I click the element, is there a way to solve this using ngModel? thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include the code where `missions` is instantiated, because the array is produced there as well.

Comment: edited the pôst! I guess it's a backend related issue cus everything seems pretty fine to me here,  I'll try to find a way to format the array into a date object if possible

Comment: Yes, the array seems to already by returned by the backend. If possible, you should adjust the backend in order to return a date string instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated backend response, couldn't figure out any other way!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).